# Store ViewModels in separate project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, entity-framework-5

I have my model in a separate class and I want to create my ViewModels in a separate class project so I can use them in different MVC projects.  Can this be done and what is the best practice for doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, very easily.

Just create the new project and reference to the existing. I tend to use something similar to the following;

**Product.Assembly.Web**
Contains the MVC project

**Product.Assembly.Web.Infrastructure**
Custom Filters, Handlers, Attributes for use in MVC

**Product.Assembly.Web.Models**
View Models

**Product.Assembly.Domain**
Service/Database Communication Layer

And of course, the tests for above.